# I am facing a rabbitmq [no connection could be made target actively refused], can some one tell why is this happening

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I am trying to connect rabbitmq to celery for a project.

```
 ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://local:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Trying again in 32.00 seconds... (16/100)
[2024-01-06 14:32:06,347: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: OperationalError('[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 472, in _reraise_as_library_errors
    yield
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 459, in _ensure_connection
    return retry_over_time(
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\functional.py", line 318, in retry_over_time
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 934, in _connection_factory
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 860, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\transport\pyamqp.py", line 203, in establish_connection
    conn.connect()
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 324, in connect
    self.transport.connect()
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\transport.py", line 129, in connect
    self._connect(self.host, self.port, self.connect_timeout)
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\transport.py", line 184, in _connect
    self.sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\worker.py", line 202, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\celery\bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\celery\bootsteps.py", line 365, in start
    return self.obj.start()
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\consumer.py", line 340, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "D:\venvs\mlops_backend_venv\lib\site-packages\celery\bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
```

I tried changing permissions in rabbitmq management interface, checked the logs, restarted the rabbitmq-server, double checked the username, password, checked whether or not port is correct and listening, disabled and enabled pluggins. Backend created the exchanges required, but queues are not (just informing if it's helpful). But the problem is still persistent.

I am new with rabbitmq and unable to understand the error. can some one explain what is this error and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The "actively refused" is saying that client's TCP 3-way handshake
failed with a RST (reset) packet being returned (or much less likely,
with ICMP administratively prohibited being returned by a firewall).

You can test this yourself, with `nc` netcat or with

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 5672
```

Currently you will see

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Once you have fixed the config, telnet and other clients
will be able to successfully connect.
So this is a quick convenient test,
handy while you're adjusting config details.
Username & password are definitely not yet relevant,
at this early stage of creating a network connection.

The big thing is to have a daemon running and listening on that port.
Additionally, it would be bad if your server is, say, 10.0.0.7,
and the daemon binds to socket identifier "10.0.0.7:5672"
instead of "127.0.0.1:5672" or equivalently to wildcard IPv4 address.

It would be bad if you have a local firewall configured
which prohibits such connection attempts.
Crank up the logging level and view its logs.

Consult the output of `netstat -an` (that's All tcp connections, Numeric ips)
to see a list of which ports your local daemons are listening on.
An entry for 5672 should come and go,
according to whether the RabbitMQ server is running or not.

Comment: I am getting

Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

Comment: also:

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:15672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:15672         127.0.0.1:50672         TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:15672         127.0.0.1:60228         TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:60216         127.0.0.1:15672         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:15672         127.0.0.1:60216         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::5672                 :::*                    LISTEN

Comment: Hmm, interesting symptom. Only this line appears to be relevant: "_tcp6 0 0 :::5672 :::* LISTEN_". That is, the daemon is listening on IPv6 and not IPv4.   `telnet` will try _both_ v4 & v6, but I suspect you told your RabbitMQ client to only try an IPv4 connection, which fails since the daemon isn't listening for incoming IPv4 connect attempts. You'll want to fix that. That 127.0.0.1 you're using is an IPv4 address; consider changing it to the 9-character string `localhost`, in hopes of _also_ trying to connect to the IPv6 ::1 loopback address.